# What is interpretability in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I read this line today :
Every regression gets better with the addition of more features or variables... But adding more features increases complexity and reduces interpretability of the model as well.
I am unable to understand what is interpretability? (searched it on google but still did not get it)

Please help thank you

Comment: Too broad & off-topic for SO; you may find this discussion @ AI useful: [Do scientists know what is happening inside artificial neural networks?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/do-scientists-know-what-is-happening-inside-artificial-neural-networks/4726#4726)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that interpretability in a regression problems is when you can explain the result of your model to non statistician / domain experts.

For example: you try to predict the size of people depending on many variable, including sex. If you use linear regression, you will be able to say that the model will add 20cm (again, for example) to the predicted size if the person is a man (compared to a woman). The domain expert will understand the relationship between explanatory variable and the predicted result, without understanding statistics or how a linear regression works.

---

In addition, I disagree with the fact that the addition of more features or variables always improve regression result.

- What is a better regression ? Improvement in choosen metrics ? For training or test set ? A "better regression" doesn't mean anything...
- If we assume that a better regression is a regression which is better to predict the target for a new dataset, more variable doesn't always improve prediction power, especially when there is no regularization, if the added feature contains futures variables or many others cases.